# if statement and checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

if user checked the checkbox1 and checkbox2 and checkbox3 then click on button1 i want the code to take him to another activity .

there is my xml file code :

```
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="stomache" />
             <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="Couphing" />
              <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="shortness of breath" />
               <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="weezing" />
                <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="Dermatitis or eczema" /> 
                <Button
              android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Determine your Doctor" />
```

So I want if statement to do something when CheckBox1 and 2 and 3 is checked .

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: i have'nt code on java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
```

inside buttons button's onclick:

```
if(cb1.isChecked()&&cb2.ischecked()&&cb3.isChecked())
{
    //start activity
}
```

Comment: create method getview() ,,  what does it mean ??

Comment: based on which context you're in it'll do different things. 
Assuming you're in an activity or a fragment, it'll return the current main view, which would probably contain your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

set onclick of btn on this

```
void start(View v)
{
       CheckBox c1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        if(c1.isChecked() &&c2.isChecked() &&c3.isChecked()  )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondAtcity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```